# Viva Graph-API not returning JSON metadata - /v1.0/employeeExperience/learningProviders

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft365

## Issue Desc

When I am trying to call - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/employeeExperience/learningProviders` with API permissions  **LearningProvider.Read, LearningProvider.ReadWrite** available into the token, but still it gives me error as below,
`"code": "forbidden", "message": "You don't have a service plan adequate for this request.",.`

Ref Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/employeeexperience-list-learningproviders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

## Question

I have checked subscriptions for my tenant with Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus` and it shows me a service plan enabled for Viva

```
"servicePlans": [
            {
                "servicePlanId": "b*********************6",
                "servicePlanName": "VIVA_LEARNING_SEEDED",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
```

Do I need to enable some more configuration for Viva ?
Please help with steps to enable this in my Tenant so that I can make Graph-API call.